# Why is it possible to query a TSV file using FORMAT='CSV' in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

I'm following an online video tutorial on Azure Synapse Analytics. The instructor used the following script:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM 
OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'taxi/raw/trip_type.tsv',
        DATA_SOURCE ='nyc_taxidata',
        FORMAT='CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION='2.0',
        HEADER_ROW=TRUE,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t'
        ) AS trip_type;
```

My question is why does the script work when the format is `FORMAT='CSV'`?

Also when I tried to use `FORMAT='TSV'` I got the following error message:

```
Parser version '2.0' is not supported for provided format 'TSV'.
```

Comment: What would you prefer? That you couldn't specify `FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t'` and it restricted you to commas so the C is consistent?

Comment: Depending on who you ask, the "C" in "CSV" doesn't have to stand for "comma", it can also stand for "character". And as well all know, the *correct* character for that is ascii 31 (though tab is *usually* a safe secondary choice because of the way UI's typically work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV stands for `Comma Separated Values`, which means by default the `FIELDTERMINATOR` is **Comma**. But it doesn't mean we cannot use any other delimiter. The delimiter could be any character like `|`, `\n`, `:`, etc., like in your case it's `\t`. Hence, whether it is `,` or any other, the file will only be called CSV and only the `DELIMITER` will change.

Coming to second part of your question.

> CSV parser version 1.0 is default and feature rich. Version 2.0 is
> built for performance and does not support all options and encodings.

Use `PARSER_VERSION='1.0'` in the 7th line of your code, and your issue will be resolved.

Refer: [How to use OPENROWSET using serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset)